# Testing Golang microservices with POSTMAN

Tags: go, postman, web-api-testing

I'm trying to test my Golang microservices with postman as the client however I cant manage the responses correctly.
The current situation is where I have a broker service that communicates with a separate authentication service to authenticate a user as shown in the code below.

```
    func Authenticate(w http.ResponseWriter,  a AuthPayload){
    //////Create a json to send to the auth microservice///////
    //Marshal the request struct into a json
    jsonData,_:=json.Marshal(a)
    log.Printf("got jsonm data as %s",jsonData)


    //////Call the auth microservice///////
    //http://{name of the authentication service in docker-compose}/{name of url we want from the auth service}
    request,err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://authentication-service:8081/authenticateuser",bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    if err!=nil{
        log.Printf("Broker service couldnt connect to the auth service, %s",err)
        return

    }

    client:=&http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Printf("Broker service client error: , %s",err)
        return

    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    //////Make sure to get back the correct status code///////
    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusUnauthorized{
        log.Println("Invalid credentials")
        return
    }else if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK{
        log.Println("Error authenticating user error code ",response.StatusCode)
        return

    }

    //Create a variable we'll read response.body (from auth service ) into
    var jsonFromAuthService jsonResponse
    //Decode the json from the auth service
    err=json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&jsonFromAuthService)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Printf("Error decoding json from auth service: , %s",err)
        return

    }
    var payload =jsonResponse{Error: false,Message: "User Authenticated",Data:jsonFromAuthService.Data}
    json.Marshal(payload)

}
```

Postman gives me status code 200 ok (which I understand means the request has been sent successfully) however I want to get the response from my auth service which would be 400 for an invalid password or email.
How can I modify the code above to return status codes from my auth service instead of POSTMAN status codes while still using postman as the client?

Comment: Start by proper handling your errors. In most cases you _must_ not continue with your code.

Comment: as Volker say or show your postman code

Comment: @Para what do you mean postman code?

Comment: @Volker I've added return statements to handle errors appropriately

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending back any status codes; so, when your code finishes executing, it's going to send back a 200 response which is what you're seeing in Postman. If you want to send other response codes at various points in your code, you can use `w.WriteHeader` and send the applicable response code. Something like this:

```golang
func Authenticate(w http.ResponseWriter,  a AuthPayload){
    jsonData,_:=json.Marshal(a)
    log.Printf("got jsonm data as %s",jsonData)

    request,err := http.NewRequest("POST", "http://authentication-service:8081/authenticateuser",bytes.NewBuffer(jsonData))
    if err!=nil {
        log.Printf("Broker service couldnt connect to the auth service, %s",err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    client:=&http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(request)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Printf("Broker service client error: , %s",err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return

    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if response.StatusCode == http.StatusUnauthorized{
        log.Println("Invalid credentials")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }
    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK{
        log.Println("Error authenticating user error code ",response.StatusCode)
        w.WriteHeader(response.StatusCode)
        return
    }


    var jsonFromAuthService jsonResponse
    err=json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&jsonFromAuthService)
    if err!=nil{
        log.Printf("Error decoding json from auth service: , %s",err)
        w.WriteHeader(response.StatusInternalServerError)
        return

    }
    var payload =jsonResponse{Error: false,Message: "User Authenticated",Data:jsonFromAuthService.Data}
    json.Marshal(payload)
}
```